# What does X[,y] denotion mean in python?

Tags: python

I was going through documentation of `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` and came across denotions such as `X[, y], X[, copy]` in methods like  `fit(X[, y])`, `inverse_transform(X[, copy])`. What do those denotions mean exactly?

Link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html

Comment: That is not Python notation, it is just documentation notation that means the parameters between the square brackets are optional. It follows common conventions on [usage messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message).

Answer (score 3):

In this case it indicates optional function arguments.

For example, [`transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.transform) is described as `transform(X[, y, copy])`, where the full function signature is `transform(X, y=’deprecated’, copy=None)`.  `X` is required, but `y` and `copy` will receive the default values if not specified.

Answer (score 1):

It means that arguments in the bracket are **optional**.

ie. `inverse_transform(X[, copy])` means you have to pass in `X` but `copy` is optional.